# iOS alternative for spring android

Tags: ios, http, rest, post

We have a working spring android frontend and ejb backend with REST/JSON POST&PUT

for porting to iOS we'r looking for a framework which can work with the old backend can u guys suggest some frameworks which will work ?

Comment: There are several frameworks out there that provide an API to access RESTful services or similar. What have you found out so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your service is fairly standard REST, then http://restkit.org/ is the way to go.